# Copy Tables from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Is there a way to copy the structure of a Salesforce install? I am making an ETL pipeline that will exist inside of Snowflake, to make it easier I want to replicate the table structure in Snowflake before uploading to a different Salesforce environment. Is there a way to extract the list in a text format (ideally in SQL)?

Comment: I do have access to Informatica, if that is a recommended tool

Answer (score 0):

Look into Heroku Connect. https://www.heroku.com/connect

Using bi-directional synchronization between Salesforce and Heroku Postgres, Heroku Connect unifies the data in your Postgres database with the contacts, accounts and other custom objects in the Salesforce database. Easily configured with a point and click UI, it’s simple to get the service up and running in minutes – no coding or complex configuration is required.